# How I can add a Google - not Gmail - account to the iOS Notes app?

Tags: ios, notes.app, accounts, google

In **Settings/Notes/Accounts/Add Account** I can add a Gmail account (eg foo@gmail.com), but a simple Google account (eg google@foo.com) I can not.

No error, or success, message is displayed during and after the process of entering username and password. At the end of the process the account is not added to the list of Notes accounts.

EDIT:

But I was able to add the same email (eg google@foo.com) in Notes app under the Mac OS X (version 10.13.6).

Only in iOS (version 10.3.3) I could not do this.

Comment: You forgot to ask a question, you simply made a statement. I have a google login me@mydomain, Email for that google account is handled elsewhere tho, and that doesn’t have the ability to use google calendar, contacts etc.

Comment: Your Google account *is* a gmail account.  Have you tried setting it up as a gmail account?

Comment: @Allan, my Google account _is not_ a Gmail account. So it's not that when I try to get into Gmail I'm redirected to the "Add Gmail to your Google Account" screen. What would "try to setting up as a Gmail account"?

Comment: What I mean by that, is set it up as gmail, but use your Google account credentials.

Comment: @Allan not all google accounts are gmail accounts.  As mentioned before, I have a me@mydomain google account used for analytics, however the MX and other mail related A records point elsewhere.  Not all google accounts are gmail accounts.

Comment: (Sigh)  I asked if you tried and in a broader sense...what else have you tried?  I'm not looking to debate the intricacies of google account characteristics.

Comment: google account is https://account.google.com/

Answer (score 1):

Google account access is true a web browser.

or apps that have access to it.

it is at https://account.google.com/

Open Safari and set it up,

go to Notes and add it.

You are adding Google services not Google account it self.

You can sync it with Mail, Contacts, or Calendars.